# TypeError in Array Traversal

Tags: solidity, arrays

solidity 0.4.17

I have an array of int128 elements, I chose in128 because I want to check for -1.

```
int128[] elements;
int128 numberOfElements;//I increment this as I add elements

function hasElement(int128 element) returns (bool) {
    for ( int128 i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++ ) {
        if (elements[i] == element) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

but I get the error:

> TypeError: Type int128 is not implicitly convertible to expected type
>   uint256 on the *i* in *elements[i]*.

Yet *i* is int128 and so are the contents of elements.

Comment: I am not pretty sure about the error. But why not use uint for `noOfElements` ?

Comment: Yes! That worked.

Comment: So I changed it to use uint for numberOfElements and the i in the for loop

Comment: Haha.. I write the answer the answer for you yesterday, but didn't click the`Post Anser` button . LOL

Comment: You must index an array with uint256. Otherwise Solidity will attempt to convert whatever you put in the index to uint256, hence the error.

Comment: and Why will it try to convert index to uint256?

Comment: That is what I found to be true ; that I can only access the contents of the array via an index that is uint256

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not pretty sure about why you can't use int128. But you cal solve your problem by using uint datatype for `noOfElements`. Keep the array as int128 (as you need this), but update the datatype for `noOfElements`.

```
int128[] elements;
uint numberOfElements;//I increment this as I add elements

function hasElement(int128 element) returns (bool) {
    for ( uint i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++ ) {
        if (elements[i] == element) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```